# What is my SQL missing?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I'm learning about PHP and MySQL. I have a lab that I'm working on where I have created a database (using the terminal in Ubuntu through a Virtual Machine) and I am trying to access this database using a PHP file.

I have created 1 database (demo) which holds 2 tables (demo_table, lab4) using this script

```
CREATE TABLE `lab4` (
 id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 first_name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 last_name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 email varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
 phone varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I can see through the terminal that they have been created the way I want, etc.

I have a php file (provided to me) in the appropriate directory (/var/www/html) which runs correctly, producing the output it is supposed to. Here is that file:

note: i have redacted my passwords!

```
<?php

function listRecords($dbc, $dbtable){
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM ".$dbtable.";";
    if($result = $dbc->query($qry)){
            if ($result->num_rows > 0){
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        foreach($row as $k=>$v){
                Print $k."  ".$v."\t";
            }
            print "\n";
                }
        } else {
                echo "Nothing to output\n";
        }
        $result->free();
} else {
        die("Error running database query for categories\n  $qry \n");
}
}

$db_conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'l*******r', '*******', 'demo');
if ($db_conn->connect_errno) {
die ("Could not connect to database server".$db_host."\n Error: ".$db_conn-
>connect_errno ."\n Report: ".$db_conn->connect_error."\n");
}

$qry = "INSERT INTO demo_table values('1', 'First User', 
'first@somewhare.com');";
$db_conn->query($qry);
$qry = "INSERT INTO demo_table values('2', 'Second User', 
'second@somewhare.com');";
$db_conn->query($qry);
$qry = "INSERT INTO demo_table values('3', 'Third User', 
'third@somewhare.com');";
$db_conn->query($qry);

listRecords($db_conn, 'demo_table');


print "\nDeleteing record 1\n";
$db_conn->query("DELETE FROM demo_table WHERE id='1';");

listRecords($db_conn, 'demo_table');

print "\nModifyingrecord 3\n";

$db_conn->query("UPDATE demo_table SET email='THIRD@newdomain.com' WHERE 
id='3';");

listRecords($db_conn, 'demo_table');

$db_conn->close();

?>
```

This was provided to me, and I have not changed it in any way from the way my instructor gave it to me. This confirms that i at least created the `demo_table` correctly.

I was tasked with creating another php file which will perform some other similar tasks (basic sql stuff). So, I have copied my instructor's `listRecords` function and then written a bunch of sql queries myself. Here is my code:

```
<?php
//A.


//function to be used in D. below
function listRecords($dbc, $dbtable)
{
$qry = "SELECT * FROM ".$dbtable.";";

if($result = $dbc->query($qry))
{
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                        foreach($row as $k=>$v)
                        {
                           Print $k."  ".$v."\t";
                        }
                        print "\n";
                }
        }  else 
        {
            echo "Nothing to output\n";
        }
        $result->free();
} else 
{
    die("Error running database query for categories\n  $qry \n");
}
}

//B.
//create a connection object
$db_conn = new mysqli('localhost', '*********', '*******', 'demo');

//IF CONNECTION FAILED: display errors
if ($db_conn->connect_errno)
{
die ("Could not connect to database server".$db_host."\n Error: ".$db_conn-
>connect_errno."\n Report: ".$db_conn->connect_error."\n");
}

//C.
//IF CONNECTION SUCCEEDED: perform SQL
//single variable name can be reused
$qry = "INSERT INTO lab4 values('First', 'User', 'first@somewhare.com', '1111111');";
$db_conn->query($qry);
$qry = "INSERT INTO lab4 values('Second', 'User', 'second@somewhare.com', '1111111');";
$db_conn->query($qry);
$qry = "INSERT INTO lab4 values('Third', 'User', 'third@somewhare.com', '1111111');";
$db_conn->query($qry);
$qry = "INSERT INTO lab4 values('Fourth', 'User', 'fourth@somewhare.com', '1111111');";
$db_conn->query($qry);
$qry = "INSERT INTO lab4 values('Fifth', 'User', 'fifth@somewhare.com', '1111111');";
$db_conn->query($qry);
$qry = "INSERT INTO lab4 values('Sixth', 'User', 'sixth@somewhare.com', '1111111');";
$db_conn->query($qry);
$qry = "INSERT INTO lab4 values('Seventh', 'User', 'seventh@somewhare.com', '1111111');";
$db_conn->query($qry);
$qry = "INSERT INTO lab4 values('Eighth', 'User', 'eighth@somewhare.com', '1111111');";
$db_conn->query($qry);
$qry = "INSERT INTO lab4 values('Ninth', 'User', 'ninth@somewhare.com', '1111111');";
$db_conn->query($qry);
$qry = "INSERT INTO lab4 values(Tenth', 'User', 'tenth@somewhare.com', '1111111');";
$db_conn->query($qry);

//D.
//display records
listRecords($db_conn, 'lab4');

//E.
//delete rows with IDs 2 and 4
$db_conn->query("DELETE from lab4 WHERE id=2");
$db_conn->query("DELETE from lab4 WHERE id=4");


//F.
//display all records after deletion in step E.
listRecords($db_conn, 'lab4');

//G.
//change email of 5th record
$db_conn->query("UPDATE lab4 SET email='newemail@somewhare.com' WHERE         id=5");

//H.
//change first name of 8th record
$db_conn->query("UPDATE lab4 SET first_name='Newname' WHERE id=8");

//I.
//change last name of 10th record
$db_conn->query("UPDATE lab4 SET last_name='Lastname' WHERE id=10");

//K.
//close the database connection
$db_conn->close();
?>
```

So I have changed some of the formatting, and changed every instance of "demo_table" to "lab4".

When I run my php (lab4.php, located in same directory as the previous code) I get the message `Nothing to output` twice. My interpretation of this is that my table is working correctly and my listRecords is working correctly (as it is not giving me the error message associated with a failed connection).

My best guess is that it is a problem with my SQL queries.

Comment: When doing an INSERT, always list the columns your inserting into, this makes your code self documenting and should help creating your records.

Comment: colour coding above shows you have syntax error(s)

Comment: @nogad Code executes so it is likely that was just from redacting credentials. (made update to reflect that)

Comment: @chris85 yes thank you it is just redacting. i have added that note in an edit. 

appreciate your time, thanks

Comment: @NigelRen why does the insert in my 1st block of code appear to work, when in my 2nd it does not work? what is the difference between them that i am not seeing?

thanks for your time

Comment: In your code, your not providing a value for the id field. If you don't list the column names your inserting, it assumes your supplying all column values.

Comment: @NigelRen thank you i will try that immediately. i was assuming that i shouldn't add an ID value as it has AUTO_INCREMENT. i must be misunderstanding that interaction. how does providing an ID value interact with the AUTO_INCREMENT? thanks again for your time

Comment: @grcHIDDEN: are you posting your questions on a mobile device? If so, please either use the Shift key on that device, or use a PC/laptop to post your questions. [The revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47518978/revisions) shows, in rev #2, some 20-30 fixes that were applied by a very patient user. It would be much better if you could take more time when composing a question, to save the time of volunteer editors. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either provide the value for the ID column, or allow the system to generate one for you ( the auto_increment).

So either...

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO lab4 values(1, 'First', 'User', 'first@somewhare.com', '1111111')";
```

Or preferably...

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO lab4 ( first_name, last_name, email, phone )
           values ('First', 'User', 'first@somewhare.com', '1111111');";
```

This will generate the id for you.

Comment: thank you very much for your time. I will try this immediately. i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

could try this way too
`
$qry = "INSERT INTO teachers ( first_name, last_name, email )
values ('Leah', 'Wairji', 'test@gmail.com');";